# What are my most optimal options on membership providers when using codefirst EF approach

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-membership

I am building an MVC3 web app and new to .NET and programming in general.

I was thinking about using the built-in ASP.NET membership provider but it seems I would have to tip toe around it, unable to cleanly link users into the rest of my entity objects and it would be a separate database too.

I just need the basics Users, Roles, Password change/retrieval. The addresses and other user specific info I take it don't have anything to do with the membership provider tables ? As in I would just need a FK relationship with the UserID etc. in one of the respective membership tables?

From what I have been reading there are ways to inherit from ASP.NET Membership Provider and implement the abstract methods for use wit EF. If that is my best bet are there any good examples or tutorials on doing so?

Rolling my own would be quite difficult I suppose, but if there's a good guide on doing so with EF codefirst I'd gladly check it out. Or maybe there's already some recommended providers on codeplex?

PS. Using sql express and will be deploying to some cheapo webhost, prolly with 1x SQL server 2008 db limit.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [MVC3 Boilerplate project on GitHub](https://github.com/crdeutsch/MVC3-Boilerplate). It has EF integration with MembershipProvider, look specifically at the [UserMembershipProvider](https://github.com/crdeutsch/MVC3-Boilerplate/tree/master/Web/Infrastructure/UserMembershipProvider) classes.

Comment: Thanks, I take it though that I must provide the implementation for the user repo and manually create User database table and create the respective POCO classes for use with EF for this to work, or are these also included in some examples in that MVC3-Boilerplate solution ?

Comment: It is all in the project. The User class and repository is already defined. This is built using Entity Framework Code First, so if the database and tables defined in the Code First classes do not exist, they will be created when the site is first run.